# What is the difference between MyClass and MyClass& in C++?

Tags: c++, reference, declaration

I'm getting my hands dirty with C++.


I come with a background in Java and C# and there's something that I don't think I understand in C++.


In these two lines:

```
Person kate("Kate");
Person& rKate = kate;
```

Does the fact that I'm using `Person` for one variable and `Person&` for the other, change in anyway how I can treat each variable later on? I understand the consequences in the calling code when declaring references as parameters of a function and then reassigning them in the function; and I understand the difference if I used a primitive type in the example above, but not for classes.

Comment: Read up on References, most good C++ books and references will cover the topic.

Comment: References are much like pointers for most use cases.

Comment: http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/references.html

Comment: In your code, `kate` and `rKate` are different names for the same object (`&kate == &rKate`). If you did `Person rKate = kate;` instead then you would be making a *copy* of the value in `kate` into a completely new `Person` object (`&kate != &rKate`).

Comment: @cdhowie:  Why doesn't the close text contain a link to the duplicate question?  I was in the midst of close voting as dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/57483/what-are-the-differences-between-a-pointer-variable-and-a-reference-variable-in?rq=1

Comment: @wallyk The link is up at the top of the question.

Comment: @cdhowie:  Nevermind, I see it up top; I saw the lower notice first.

Comment: "I understand the difference if I used a primitive type in the example above, but not for classes". It is exactly the same for primitive types and for classes. C++ does not give class types special treatment in the manner of Java and C#.

Comment: @molbdnilo That answers my question. I had no idea that the `kate` object would be physically copied in memory just by reassigning it to another non-reference variable.